# java.lang.NullPointerException in a sample program of Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

i am try to run a sample application of hibernate, it give me a error on run time:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at transaction.rollback();

this is in Main.java:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Address address = new Address("ABC", "Delhi", "TN", "110001");
        Student student = new Student("kumar", address);
        session.save(student);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

Comment: Do you know which line it's failing on?

Comment: You can see from the exception output that it was thrown from the main method on a call to transaction.rollback()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should change

```
transaction.rollback();
```

to

```
if (transaction != null) {
    transaction.rollback();
}
```

as its possible for the assignment of transaction to throw an exception.

If you want to get rid of the Log4J messages, you can add a call to

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

to setup basic logging

Comment: where i should write this line: BasicConfigurator.configure();

Comment: Make it the first line in the main method, you can read more about log4j here - http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html but note, its been "superceeded" by logback http://logback.qos.ch/